# не подгружаются сниппеты и пути в Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Мне очень нравится VS Code. Не хочется менять его из-за этого. Проблема в следующем:
   [image]
при нажатии клавиш ctrl + space постоянно показывает Loading...

После перезапуска VS все работает, но не долго[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и путь файла - такая же проблема[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Please help!